# Get file that was modified in the last 5 days in an compressed archive on a USB key

Tags: linux, archive

Like the title said I want to put all file in my home that was modified in the last 5 days in a archive file. Also, I want to put the file "5DaysFile" in my usb key. The usb key root in my systeme is `/media/alec/backup/atelier5/`. I tried using something like
`Find ~/ -mtime -5 -ls | grep tar czf /media/alec/backup/atelier5/5DaysFile.tar`
but, it didn't work.

So how can I do it with one command line.

Comment: What's the `grep` supposed to do in your try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one liner

```
find ~ -mtime 5 | xargs tar czf media/alec/backup/atelier5/5DaysFile.tar.gz
```

Note that there is a lot of application data in your home directory that is modified and will be backed up.